# angularjs popover overlap with ui-select when dropdown opens

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui

[image]

when angularjs ui-select drop-down opens popover overlap with each other as shown in the screenshot.

```
 <div class="form-group required">
    <a href="" class="fa icon-info" popover-placement="left" popover="{{'dfgf_popover'|lang}}" ></a>
    <ui-select required ng-model="country.selected" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
       <ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">
          <span>{{$select.selected.name}}</span>
          <button class="clear" ng-click="clear($event)">X</button>
       </ui-select-match>
       <ui-select-choices repeat="country in countries | filter: $select.search">
          <span ng-bind-html="country.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
          <small ng-bind-html="country.code | highlight: $select.search"></small>
       </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

how to write css code to fix this issue.

Comment: We need a demo, is hard to say what is the problem in this context.

Comment: you can use z-index

Comment: while ui-select choices dropdown open and popover click to show, popover eliment move to on top of ui-select element.i stiil couldnt figure out why.